# Trying to install Xcode on Yosemite 10.10.5

Tags: xcode

I'm trying to install Xode 7 beta 6 version on Yosemite. I used the command 'Xcode-select --install' in terminal. It says 'xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates.' But i'm using latest version of OS X. What should i do? Please help me...

Comment: Have you used AppStore/Software update to install Xcode?

Comment: Yes! I used AppStore/Software

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to install Xcode 7 on OS X 10.10. There's your problem. If you read the developer website, it would tell you it can only be installed on OS X 10.11. No exceptions. My advice would be to either: a) use a new computer to test Xcode 7 and El Capitan, b) Use a new partition for that, or c) Wait for the official releases within a month or so.

Comment: Thanks BobRon! I installed Xcode 6.4 and it is working fine.

Comment: @user143297 you should mark the answer correct

Comment: Actually, the latest Xcode version supported on Yosemite is 7.2.1.  If you've downloaded it previously from MAS, you can find it in your purchased page.

Comment: I can confirm, this answer is absolutely incorrect.  Version 7.2.1 just installed just fine on my 10.10.  Version 7.3 is the first version that requires 10.11.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 7.2.1 should install correctly. This version of Xcode is currently working on my MacBook Pro running OS X 10.10.5 Yosemite.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 7 requires a Mac running OS X version 10.10.4 or later. It includes SDKs for watchOS 2.0, iOS 9, and OS X version 10.11.
based on web https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_7_0.html

Comment: His computer matches those specs, but not the ones required (as shown by a different answer). This answer also doesn't seem to provide reasoning or any solution really.